# Python Flask Request Form: How to Access the val attribute of the option child element of a select element

Tags: python, flask

I was searching the web, but could not find an answer.

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form action="/funcation_create_call" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user1">Select a Provider</label>
        <select name="user1" class="form-control" id="user1">
            <option val="3">MCI MCI</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user2">Select a Receiver</label>
        <select name="user2" class="form-control" id="user2">
            <option val="2">Sam San</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Call!</button>
</form>
```

and the following Python code:

Code: `request.form.get('user1')`

My goal is to be able to extract the *val* attribute (e.g. 3) from the option element, but instead, i always get the element text (e.g. MCI MCI)

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `<option value='3'...`, rather than `val`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 thanks for pointing this out. After I fix my typo, everything works as expected. Thanks again!!!